# Order by from another context

Tags: c#, sql, linq, telerik-open-access

I am struck up with some strange situation (may be strange only for me!).

I have some table like `StudentMerit`. It has columns `StudentId`, `Marks`. There is another table called `StudentDetails` which has `StudentId`, `StudentName`.

I need to query it like

```
select a.StudentId, a.Marks, b.StudentName 
from StudentMerit a, StudentDetails b 
where a.StudentId = b.StudentId 
order by StudentName ASC, Marks DESC
```

I am using Telerik ORM for data access now and I need the output of my query as class type `StudentMerit`. So I cannot directly convert the above query to Linq like this:

```
var query = context.StudentMerit
    .SelectMany(
        r => context.StudentDetails
            .Where(rp => rp.StudentId==.StudentId)
            .DefaultIfEmpty(),
        (r,rp) => new
                  {
                      r.StudentId,
                      r.Marks,
                      rp.StudentName 
                  })
    .OrderBy(c=>c.StudentName)
    .ThenByDescending(c=> c.Marks);
```

Because It returns output as anonymous type. I don't need `StudentName` in the select query but need it sort the query.

Is there any way to do this with directly sorting based on `StudentName` without joining the tables?

Please help me out.

Comment: I have already included `SelectMany` .. so no need of `select` i guess

Comment: Can you give me what are you expected and what is the properties in yours class ?

Comment: I am expecting the query like `var query = context.StudentMerit
    .OrderBy(<some condition to sort based on StudentName here>)
    .ThenByDescending(c=> c.Marks); ` this. Is it possible to write the condition in `orderby` with respect to StudentId

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your query using join like this:

```
var query = from m in context.StudentMerit
            join s in context.StudentDetails on m.StudentId equals s.StudentId
            orderby s.StudentName , m.Marks
            select new
            {
                StudentId = m.StudentId,
                Marks = m.Marks,
                StudentName = s.StudentName 
            };
```

When using the latest version of Telerik Data Access, the query produces the following SQL (with some beautification):

```
SELECT a.StudentId AS COL1, a.Marks AS COL2, b.StudentName AS COL3 
FROM StudentMerit a 
JOIN StudentDetails AS b ON (a.StudentId = b.StudentId) 
ORDER BY COL2, COL3
```

Another option if you have 1:M association between StudentMerit and StudentDetails is to use a reference navigation property (`... StudentName = m.Student.StudentName...`) in your projection and skip the explicit JOIN. This should produce the same SQL and results.